# How can I let users upload videos to website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, paperclip

I am trying to let users upload videos to my site. I am using ruby on rails with windows. I am also using devise for user authentication. What do I need to do to let them upload videos? Someone told me I can use paperclip, but I'm not exactly sure how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try : Install Paperclip and 
Model class**

```
    validates_attachment :videos,
        content_type: ['video/mp4'],
        message:      "Sorry, only MP4 Videos allow",
        if:           :is_video?

  private

  def is_video?
    url.instance.attachment_content_type =~ %r(video)
  end
```